# How can I programmatically change the Scale of the Rect Transform component in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, scale, rect

I'd like to programmatically modify the Scale parameter (specifically the x Scale) of the Rect Transform component attached to my 'damage pop-up' game object, as shown in the attached image; however, I just can't seem to modify this value.  I've tried several methods (code shown below) and nothing seems to work.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Rect Transform component in Unity (image):
[image: Rect Transform component in Unity (image)]

```cs
Vector3 rectScale;
RectTransform rectTransform;
float xScale;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
         
    rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    rectScale = rectTransform.localScale;
    rectScale = new Vector3(3f, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z); //this doesn't work
    xScale = rectTransform.localScale.x;
    xScale = *any number*; // this doesn't work
   
}

void Update()
{
    rectScale = new Vector3(3f, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z); //this doesn't work
    xScale = *any number* //this doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The issue here seems to be more a misunderstanding how c# works in general!

The

```c#
xScale = 3f;
```

assigns a new value to the field `xScale`. Whatever value it had before is now forgotten and it is `3f` now. The same as

```c#
rectScale = new Vector3(3f, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
```

assigns a new value to the field `rectScale`. Whatever vector value it had before is forgotten and it now has the value `(3f, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z)`

**Both do NOT change the value of `rectTransform.localScale` or `rectTransform.localScale.x`!**

You rather want to assign a new value to `rectTransform.localScale` like e.g.

```c#
recTransform.localScale = new Vevtor3 (3f, rectTransform.localScale.y, rectTransform.localScale.z);
```

Or a bit more efficient without accessing the same property multiple times

```c#
var scale = rectTransform.localScale;
scale.x = 3f;
recTransform.localScale = scale;
```

---

Btw specifically for `RectTransform` you might rather want to use [`sizeDelta`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-sizeDelta.html) which scales the actual `rect`. Using `localScale` will cause the content and any children to look **stretched**!

```c#
var scale = rectTransform.sizeDelta:
scale.x = 3f;
recTransform.sizeDelta = scale;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much derHugo; the answer seems so obvious once someone explains it to you lol.  Lucky for me, since I'm a human the more humility involved with this lesson the more indelible it is!   Thank you also for the "sizeDelta" suggestion... I'm going to play with it now!

Comment: If this solved your question please feel free to accept it ;)

Comment: @KyleS. Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) this answer if it helped you.